# Smart device Application in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-phone-7, smart-device

Im learning basics in smart device application development.i developed small app using USA windows mobile 5.0 Pocket PC emulator. Im having basic doubts regarding emulator and deployment.

1.According to the smart phone devices we have to download emulator and develop applications or else default emulator will support for all windows devices?

2.How to deploy and install those deployed those files into my windows phone

Answer (score 0):

Windows Mobile applications are not compatible with Windows Phone.

To develop Windows Phone application you need to install Windows Phone SDK. It will install WP emulator and a bunch of tools. You'll be able to deploy application to emulator or device using Visual Studio or tool called XAPDeploy which comes along with Windows Phone SDK.

Is this what are you asking for?